# Save files locally, but prevent them from showing up in the users file manager

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-3, cordova-plugins

Using PhoneGap 3.2 and the File API, I'm downloading a set of images to display in the app. I create a folder named "Appname" and put all the files there. On Android this folder is accessible through the file manager, and on some models the images show up in the users image gallery.

Is it possible to save files locally, but prevent them from showing up to the user outside of the app?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, no. Especially if the client has root access.

You may try the followings to mitigate the problem:

a) Name your files to start with a DOT (.) so that it is recognized as hidden file. (Still, a file manager configured to show hidden files can show it).

b) Store the file instead on some databases in the /data/data/your.app.packages path, which is by default only accessible to your app. (Still a root user can see it).

c) A linux trick. Create a file, open it, hold the file descriptor but remove the file. In this way the file is removed from the directory structure so that it doesn't show up in the FS layer (and thus inaccessible). To make it permanent, use the file descriptor you hold to create a link (or dig into the `/proc` directory tree to make links with files under `fd`.

Since this trick works on linux, I guess it should work on Android. But it's probably overkill.

d) Other stopgaps include encryption, obfuscation, etc. But they don't exactly fall into the kind you are looking for.

Comment: Hi, I am currently on step 3 but I am stuck, because I need to get the reference which the file descriptor is pointing to before I close the file descriptor. Any help or guidance will be greatly appreciated.